# primefaces:datatable: custom filter: "contains" instead of "beginning"

Tags: primefaces, filter

By default, primeface filter dataTable's rows, by finding rows that columns begins with the string entered in the search area.
How do I filter the DataTable rows that the column ***contains*** (not begins with) the string  entered in the search area?

Comment: Normally you should start with reading the docs…

Answer (score 12):

You can do this using `filterMatchMode` attribute on `p:column` of the dataTable. A very good example can be found on [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml).

So if we take the above mentioned example, you could have roughly something like this:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtFilterView.cars}" widgetVar="carsTable"
    filteredValue="#{dtFilterView.filteredCars}">

    <p:column filterBy="#{car.id}" headerText="Id" footerText="contains"
        filterMatchMode="contains">

        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The attribute `filterMatchMode` accepts values such as contains, endsWith, startsWith, exact...

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider marking this answer as accepted to make it easier for other people to find. Thanks!

Comment: ""Glad to help. Please consider marking this answer as accepted to make it easier for other people to find. Thanks!""

but how to do this?

Comment: There is a grey "check" icon next to this answer, right below the voting buttons ... or you can see it explained in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour